# Composite Key when a key is a class

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying make a composite-key at JPA, which one of this keys is a class and the another is an Enumeration.

But it is giving the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: br.com.model.Restaurante, at table: ImagemRestaurante, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(restaurante)]
```

ImagemRestaurante.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ImagemRestauranteId.class)
public class ImagemRestaurante implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4650712996667906167L;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="idRestaurante")
    private Restaurante restaurante;

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private TipoImagemRestaurante tipoImagemRestaurante;

    private String nome;

    private String formato;

    private Long tamanho;

    private Integer altura;

    private Integer largura;

    @Transient
    private String caminho;

    @Transient
    private String caminhoHTML;

    public ImagemRestaurante() {
    }

    // Get Sets

}
```

ImagemRestauranteId.java

```
    public class ImagemRestauranteId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6216145537667024048L;

    private Restaurante restaurante;

    private TipoImagemRestaurante tipoImagemRestaurante;

    public ImagemRestauranteId() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( ! (obj instanceof ImagemRestauranteId ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        ImagemRestauranteId imaId = (ImagemRestauranteId) obj;
        return (imaId.restaurante == restaurante) &&
                (imaId.tipoImagemRestaurante == tipoImagemRestaurante);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return restaurante.hashCode() + tipoImagemRestaurante.hashCode();
    }
    // Get Sets

}
```

Restaurante.java

```
    @Entity
    public class Restaurante {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idRestaurante;

    private String nmRestaurante;

    private String dsRestaurante;

    @OneToOne
    private Telefone telefone;

    @OneToOne
    private Endereco endereco;

    private Boolean permitirComentario;

    private Boolean permitirNota;

    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;

    public Restaurante() {
    }
    // Get Sets
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `@ManyToOne` mapping to relationship with `Restaurante`

  `@Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="idRestaurante")
  private Restaurante restaurante;`

Existence of ImagemRestaurante instance depends on existance of Restaurante instance. That's why Restaurante is called *parent* in relation to ImagemRestaurante by the JPA spec

> If an Id attribute in the entity is a many-to-one or one-to-one relationship to a parent
>   entity, the corresponding attribute in the id class must be of the same Java type as the
>   id class or embedded id of the parent entity (if the parent entity has a composite primary
>   key) or the type of the Id attribute of the parent entity (if the parent entity has a
>   simple primary key).

- Change `private Restaurante restaurante;` to `private Long restaurante;` in `ImagemRestauranteId` class. The ImagemRestauranteId being an IdClass has to hold only the PK reference to Restaurante. Following words from JPA spec apply

> A simple primary key or a field or property of a composite primary key should be one of the following
>   types: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; *java.lang.String;
>   java.util.Date; java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger*.